# Joomla article wont post if the content is over 3000 characters

Tags: articles

I am running into an issue where my article will not post if the content of the article is over 3000 characters. When I click save, it appears to be trying to post but then I am taken to a white screen.

I am using JCE Editor but I have also tried Tiny MCE and nothing works. I have also disabled by JCH Optimize plugin but this still does not solve the issue.

Any ideas how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do your error logs say?  A white screen is often a PHP error.

Comment: Hi there,I was informed that this is a known joomla 3.7.x bug and it only started happening once I updated from 3.6.x.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely a ModSecurity rule being triggered. This ModSecurity rule is triggered when PCRE engine limits are exceeded. You will need to whitelist that rule. See [this post](http://www.itoctopus.com/internal-server-error-when-trying-to-save-content-on-a-joomla-website) about this. Alternatively, you can increase your ModSecurity PCRE limits, but this will likely increase the impact of a DoS attack, as PCRE matching is heavy on the system.